# Eclipse not starting in Windows 10 (Issues with workspace)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

So when I start Eclipse, it says that it cannot be started and that I should check my log files in the work space file, any solution on how to fix this? 
The eclipse files are stored on my D drive while the workspace is on my C drive if that makes any difference.

If i check the plugin file with workspaceNew there are only 3 files:

```
org.eclipse.core.resources
org.eclipse.core.runtime
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
```

Below is the contents of the most recent log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-09 17:08:26.253
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getCSSSWTEngine(ThemeEngineManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getEngineForDisplay(ThemeEngineManager.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createThemeEngine(PartRenderingEngine.java:1428)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1281)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.StyleSheet cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.100.v20140424-2042
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Which Java version do you use (in your log file see `java.version=...` above the error you posted)?

Comment: Seems like the version is 9 `!SESSION 2017-10-09 17:08:23.988 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=9
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product`

Comment: Eclipse doesn't work with Java 9 unless the eclipse.ini is modified. If you want to use Java 9 wait for Eclipse Oxygen.1a to be released on 11 October.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that version of the eclipse and jdk are same as your system i.e. If you are running 32 bit system then make sure eclipse and jdk is also 32 bit

**edit** eclipse luna requires jdk 7 or up