# i am trying to install eclipse but it shows java was started but returned exit code 13

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to install the eclipse ee for java and am getting an error ie. java was started but returned exit code 13. i am attaching a screen shot for the same.
[image]

please help me on this.

Comment: What is the content of your `eclipse.ini`?

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and are almost certainly trying to run it with the 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Comment: Which jdk version you currently have, and if I am not wrong your eclipse is oxygen right?? Oxygen requires jdk 1.8 also this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46650922/8587776